# Java script: If focus of user is out of window then show alert

Tags: javascript

I am trying to start a online quiz website. If the user entered the quiz page, he should not be able to search for answer on the other tab or other window on the computer. By this we will get the correct answer from the correct person. I found that we can make this with JavaScript.

Comment: You won't be able to control anything outside of the current browser window. You will have to developer a special browser or program to control stuff like this.

Comment: Set a max time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome you can do this:

```
window.onblur = function(){
    alert("Blurred");
}
```

I haven't tested any other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do that with JavaScript. JavaScript can not control the browser for security reasons.

Comment: Hey see the below answer. It is good. Even you can learn on seeing it.

Comment: So they call the blur event that can be triggered by multiple things. It will not prevent them from minimizing the browser and doing something else.

Comment: Ok. But instead of alert, I will use other functions which I need.